# Running Knex migrations during build with process Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, knex.js

I am able to run migrations once the application has started. But am having trouble with making the migrations run before the application has started.

My database connection is through Private IP and basic auth. Again this works when the application is running, but ideally migrations should be run before the application starts.

I would rather **not run google cloud proxy**.

I am using `gcp-build` to run the following:

```
Step #1: > yarn db:migrate
Step #1: 
Step #1: yarn run v1.17.3
Step #1: $ knex-migrate up
Step #1: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

But that ends up showing a pool

Answer (score 1):

Private IP connections only work if the device you are connecting is also on the Virtual Private Cloud (VPC). You can't connect from outside that network. See the Private IP docs on [environment requirements for more information](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#environment_requirements).

Comment: That is good information thank you for your response, but the vpc I'm trying to connect from is on the private network, and it does actually work once the application is running. I can run migrations by triggering an endpoint in the app, but I wanted to run them before the app actually starts using gcp-build or something like it.